# Python Compare 2 CSV's delete differences

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 1 CSV that is heavily manipulated, it looks something like this:

`"ID","Vulnerability","Report Category","IP","DNS","NetBIOS","OS",
"x","Title","Category Type","x.x.x.x","DNS Name","Net Name","Windows"`

The 2nd CSV looks like this:

`"IP","DNS","NetBIOS","OS","Title","x.x.x.x","DNS Name","Net Name","Operating System","Title"`

What I am needing to do is compare the 2 CSV's based on certain columns.
 
On CSV 1 I want to compare column B(Vulnerability) and column D(IP) with CSV 2 column E(Title) and column A(IP). For the purposes of this argument CSV1 column B(Vulnerability) will match CSV column E's(Title) data exactly.
Once it finds matches it will delete the rows that match on CSV 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know you can use pandas so just load both csv files into dataframes and then join the tables and delete where they match.

For example:

```
csv2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'col2' : [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]})
csv1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : [1, 3, 4], 'col2' : [10, 12, 13]})
print(csv2.loc[~csv2.set_index(list(csv2.columns)).index.isin(csv1.set_index(list(csv1.columns)).index)])
```

In this example you will keep all values from csv2 which are not in csv1.

## This should be more memory efficient:

```
merged = csv2.merge(csv1, how="left", left_on=["Title", "IP"], right_on=["Vulnerability", "IP"])
print(merged.loc[merged['Vulnerability'].isnull()])
```

This does a left join (keeping all values in csv2) and filters so that only values which do not match to csv1 are kept.

Comment: I know that I can load them both in. Where I am getting stuck is comparing the 2 columns with each other then deleting the rows on CSV 2

Comment: This works. However, in CSV 1 it seems to be to large. When I do the following df=pd.read_csv(csv1, nrows=10) it works. When I exclude the nrows pandas is getting a memory error. Any way to go about including all the data in CSV1?

Comment: How big is csv1?

Comment: @Wo0o See my edit. This should help memory management as the other solution did a lot of the comparison on the fly (which can be very memory intensive). Let me know how it goes

Comment: I am getting the following error when I run the memory efficient one above: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'merge' `import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

csv1 = 'C:\\Users\\NAME\\Desktop\\Vulnerability Reporting.csv'

#Filepath of the CSV to be read
csv2 = 'C:\\Users\\NAME\\Downloads\\Scan_Results_20170503_scan_1493777008_09650.csv'

merged = csv2.merge(csv1, how="left", left_on=["Title", "IP"], right_on=["Vulnerability", "IP"])

print(merged.loc[merged['Vulnerability'].isnull()])`

Comment: You have to load the csv into a pandas dataframe, as before, then you can use the .merge function. Sorry for not clarifying

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond back. This worked. Thanks for your help.